# JSON error - Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'

Tags: json

I have a big json file but don't know it shows some error...

```
{
  "_index": "ttmnt",
  "_type": "********ils",
  "_id": "********DC",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "_id": "********DC",
    "policyNo": "********461",
    "displayPolicyNo": "********461",
    "email": "********@GMAIL.COM",
    "name": "********",
    "mobileNo": "********",
    "misOwner": "********sh.w@t********t.com",
    "registrationNo": "dd578",
    "folderNo": "dddddYDC"
  }
}
{
  "_index": "ttmnt",
  "_type": "********c",
  "_id": "********DC",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "_id": "********DC",
    "policyNo": "********21s",
    "displayPolicyNo": "s008461",
    "email": "****A@GMAIL.COM",
    "name": "********HAL",
    "mobileNo": "********99906",
    "misOwner": "********sh.w@t********t.com",
    "registrationNo": "********8",
    "folderNo": "********YDC"
  }
}
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'
```

It validates correctly if I only use 1st raw

```
{
  "_index": "ttmnt",
  "_type": "********ils",
  "_id": "********DC",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "_id": "********DC",
    "policyNo": "********461",
    "displayPolicyNo": "********461",
    "email": "********@GMAIL.COM",
    "name": "********",
    "mobileNo": "********",
    "misOwner": "********sh.w@t********t.com",
    "registrationNo": "dd578",
    "folderNo": "dddddYDC"
  }
}
```

I am not able to find the problem here.. both lines have same value same thing but it gives error when I place second raw.

Comment: What do you do to get this error? Both blocks in your question have unbalanced braces `{` and `}` and are therefore malformed. I don't know which program you use to validate the JSON code, but I am surprised that the second block is considered valid.